# Angular 4 - Django: "Unsupported media type \"text/plain\" in request."

Tags: json, angular, typescript, django-rest-framework

I am working with a web app. I've frontend in Angular 4 and backend in Django Rest.

When I want receive information since the API it works wonderfull, but when I try to send datas to save in the data base with the API I have this error: `"Unsupported media type \"text/plain\" in request."`.

I think that my API configuration is rigth, because I've researching and I find the same error and the trouble is in Angular. I've tryed all I've found, but nothing work to me.

This is my Angular code for this:

```
enviar() {
    var body = '"schema_name":"pruebanm","fecha_alta":"2018-02-01","nombre":"cliente","ubicacion":"prueba","telefono":"1234567","correo":"cliente@prueba.com","activo":true';
    this.http.post("http://tenant1.intrainingls.com:8000/viewSets/cliente/", JSON.stringify(body)).subscribe((data) => {});
}
```

I hope somebody can help me to find the solution. (data in body is to try)

PD. And if you need more information, please, tell me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The body of your HTTP request must be an object:

```
var body = { "schema_name":"pruebanm","fecha_alta":"2018-02-01","nombre":"cliente","ubicacion":"prueba","telefono":"1234567","correo":"cliente@prueba.com","activo":true };
```

And there is no need to stringify it:

```
enviar() {
    var body = '"schema_name":"pruebanm","fecha_alta":"2018-02-01","nombre":"cliente","ubicacion":"prueba","telefono":"1234567","correo":"cliente@prueba.com","activo":true';
    this.http.post("http://tenant1.intrainingls.com:8000/viewSets/cliente/", body).subscribe((data) => {});
}
```

https://angular.io/guide/http#making-a-post-request

Answer (score 8):

As specified in the error "you are using a wrong media type".

Change it to `application/json`:

[image]